# Генерация checksum на JS с последующей проверкой на PHP для порции данных

Tags: javascript, php

Собственно посоветуйте каким образом можно сгенерировать контрольную сумму для некоторой порции данных (текст, часть считанного файла) - для проверки целостности. Отправка JavaScript (ajax), обработка PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Любой алгоритм подсчёта контрольных сумм будет возвращать одинаковый результат на всех языках программирования. Для PHP есть встроенные функции (например, [SHA1](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sha1.php)) Для JS можно использовать сторонние решения ([CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js) или [эта](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha1)) или написать свой(тут, опять же, можно посмотреть исходники готовых решений.)

Comment: т.е. встроенных в JS, которым есть аналоги в PHP, нету?

Comment: В современных браузерах есть тот же SHA1 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest#Parameters

Comment: Зависит от списка поддерживаемых вами браузеров. Для старых такой возможности не будет.

Comment: и что тогда придумать для старых?

Comment: Что для старых написал в ответе - использовать готовое решение или писать своё